# Is there a way to deactivate LDAP contacts suggestion on android 6.0?

Tags: contacts, accounts

When I write emails, android suggests plenty of contacts as recipient because my email is connected to an exchange enterprise account. But the company is very big and at every mail, I have suggestion of plenty of contacts *before* to see my personal contacts. This behavior is not very efficient : if you write a lot of emails to a person, she would be in your contacts list and you don't want other suggestion before her!

So, is there a way to deactivate LDAP contacts suggestions on android?

Comment: Go to Settings -> Accounts & Sync and disable Contact Sync for that account.  You will probably have to clear the data from Contacts/Contacts Storage afterward and re-sync any personal accounts.

Comment: @MatthewRead I had tried to remove contacts sync for this account but suggestions are still here. Could you explain me how to purge contacts storage data?

Comment: Under Settings -> Applications, find the app(s) and hit Clear Data.

Comment: @MatthewRead not working... still LDAP suggestions

Comment: You might need to clear the data for the Email app too, though then you'll need to re-sync all your email.  It's also possible that your work contacts have been synced to your personal account.